# Bootstrap multiple collapse togglers in same navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm just getting started trying to make a new bootstrap site and want to have the search bar as part of a seperate collapse toggle. Essentially on the right of the navbar I want the search bar toggle and then the menu toggle.

I have the following questions:

1. How can I alight the two buttons so they sit next to each other on the right side? One of them seems to sit in the middle right now and I'm not sure why.
2. Since I separated the form into a different DIV it seems to not align to the right side of the page anymore, it is indented a bit. Why is that?
3. I only one of the collapsed menus to be open at a time. E.g. if the search is open and I tap the menu toggle I want it to close the search and vice versa.

This is what I have so far. I know it's near default but I'm just getting started and am quite new to bootstrap.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap - Prebuilt Layout</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
      
      
      
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSearch" aria-controls="navbarSearch" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
               <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
           

           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                 <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                       <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
            
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSearch">
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center">
       <h1 class="display-4">Bootstrap with Dreamweaver</h1>
       <p class="lead">Easily build your page using the Bootstrap components from the Insert panel.</p>
       <hr class="my-4">
       <p>This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
       <p class="lead">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
       </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="row text-center">
          <div class="col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">Click outside the blue container to select this <strong>row</strong>. Columns are always contained within a row. <strong>Rows are indicated by a dashed grey line and rounded corners</strong>. </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <hr>
       <br>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                   <br><br>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                   <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                   <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
             </div>
             <br>
             <br/>
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                   Featured
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                   <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="images/card-img.png" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                   <p class="card-text">Some text to build on the card's content.</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                   <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                   <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="card-body">
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                   <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div class="row">
          <div class=" col-md-4"> Click here to select this<strong> column.</strong> Always place your content within a column. Columns are indicated by a dashed blue line. </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>resize a column</strong> using the handle on the right. Drag it to increase or reduce the number of columns.</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 "> You can <strong>offset a column</strong> using the handle on the left. Drag it to increase or reduce the offset. </div>
       </div>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h3>Adding <strong>Buttons</strong></h3>
                   <p>Quickly add buttons to your page by using the button component in the insert panel. </p>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Info Button</button>
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Success Button</button>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center col-md-6">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                   <h3>Adding <strong>Badges</strong></h3>
                   <p>Using the insert panel, add badge to your page by using the badge component.</p>
                   <span class="badge badge-info">Info Badge</span> <span class="badge badge-danger">Danger Badge</span>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
       <br>
       <hr>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="text-center col-lg-6 offset-lg-3">
             <h4>Footer </h4>
             <p>Copyright &copy; 2020 &middot; All Rights Reserved &middot; <a href="#" >My Website</a></p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-4.4.1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.: Simply add them to a separate node. The container has a flex-settings set, which align the child-nodes to fill 100% width with automatical spacing.

To overcome this, a new child node or different flex-settings are required.

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Demo</a>
  <div>
    <a ...></a>
    <a ...></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I mentioned this behavior some time ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64958131/10304804).

2.: The class .container adds margin to the left and right side and is flex-container, which varies by the [break-point](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/). Other classes like .row compensate this and use negative values to rearrange the content.

[image: margin of row]

Bootstrap also offers example which will help you with the alignment in the navbar using ml-auto.

3.: If you want to open only one at a time, you should combine the buttons with the tab-handling. The [accordion example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/#accordion-example) might be the right choice. In the end it doesn't matter where you place the buttons or links, as long as the ids match with the content they have to display.